# Circle looks jagged and not very smooth in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I created a circle that zooms in and fades out once it reaches a certain scale. When I open it on Google chrome, the edges of the circle looks perfect and crisp. But on a Safari, the edge of the circle looks really bad and faded out. I added "webkit" and its still the same. Is it just that the css animation is not compatible with Safari? Here is my code.

Picture of how the edges look in chrome
https://gyazo.com/91a2faecb48703c4ed7e47bc3035b802

Picture of how the edges look in Safari
https://gyazo.com/0507f9bb35eb2e0fd21b620d3ba44538

Html

```
 <ul id="bubbles">

        <li id="firstCircle"></li>



        </ul>
```

CSS

```
 #bubbles li{
              position: relative;
                list-style: none;
                display: block;
                border-radius: 100%;
              animation: fadeAndScale 15s ease-in infinite;
              -webkit-animation: fadeAndScale 15s ease-in infinite;
              -ms-animation: fadeAndScale 15s ease-in infinite;
              -moz-animation: fadeAndScale 15s ease-in infinite;
              -o-animation: fadeAndScale 15s ease-in infinite;
          }

          #bubbles li:nth-child(1){
              width: 100px;
              height: 100px;
              background-color: red;
          }
          @keyframes fadeAndScale{
              0%{
                  z-index: 100;
                  transform: scale(0)
              }
              100%{
                  z-index: 0;
                  transform: scale(50);
              }
          }
          @-webkit-keyframes fadeAndScale{
              0%{
                  z-index: 100;
                  -webkit-transform: scale(0)
              }
              100%{
                  z-index: 0;
                  -webkit-transform: scale(50);
              }
          }
```

Comment: Safari has a lot of problems with CSS, but it's probably a combination of the border-radius and animation.

Comment: So should I remove the border radius ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a round dot svg image and then proceed to use css to animate the scaling.

Edit: This is how that site is approaching it...

```css
.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #1C96FF 0%, #00FFC9 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1C96FF 0%, #00FFC9 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper>div {
  will-change: transform;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-left: -250px;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper>div:not(._touch) {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .indiez-fow-bg-wrapper>div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -150px;
  }
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__violet {
  left: 25%;
  top: 15%;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__violet._touch {
  left: auto;
  right: -10%;
  top: 5%;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__violet:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #411AFA 4%, #9400FF 74%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #411AFA 4%, #9400FF 74%);
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__red {
  top: 25%;
  right: 5%;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s 4.5s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s 4.5s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__red:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #F14545 0%, #E7219B 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #F14545 0%, #E7219B 100%);
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__red._touch {
  right: auto;
  left: 25%;
  top: 30%;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s 3s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s 3s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__mint {
  top: 200px;
  left: 20%;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s 9s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s 9s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__mint:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #01C961 0%, #00FFA2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #01C961 0%, #00FFA2 100%);
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__mint._touch {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s 6s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s 6s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__sunflower {
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s 13.5s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s 13.5s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__sunflower:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFB100 0%, #FFE938 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FFB100 0%, #FFE938 100%);
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__sunflower._touch {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s 9s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s 9s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__purple {
  top: 300px;
  left: 10%;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s 18s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s 18s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__purple:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FF519F 0%, #BE42FF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF519F 0%, #BE42FF 100%);
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__purple._touch {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s 12s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s 12s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__royal-blue {
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s 22.5s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s 22.5s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__royal-blue:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #2500DA 0%, #009BFF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #2500DA 0%, #009BFF 100%);
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__royal-blue._touch {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s 15s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s 15s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__orange {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s 27s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s 27s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__orange:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FF4040 0%, #FF9A3D 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF4040 0%, #FF9A3D 100%);
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__orange._touch {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s 18s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s 18s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__lime {
  top: 25%;
  right: 200px;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s 31.5s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s 31.5s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__lime:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #79E200 0%, #B2951B 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #79E200 0%, #B2951B 100%);
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__lime._touch {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s 21s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s 21s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__aqua {
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 20s 36s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 20s 36s linear forwards;
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__aqua:not(._touch) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #1C96FF 0%, #00FFC9 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1C96FF 0%, #00FFC9 100%);
}

.indiez-fow-bg-wrapper._animate .__aqua._touch {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUp 16s 12s linear forwards;
  animation: scaleUp 16s 12s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleUp {
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="indiez-fow-bg-wrapper  _animate">
  <div class="__violet ">

  </div>
  <div class="__red ">

  </div>
  <div class="__mint ">

  </div>
  <div class="__sunflower ">

  </div>
  <div class="__purple ">

  </div>
  <div class="__royal-blue ">

  </div>
  <div class="__orange ">

  </div>
  <div class="__lime ">

  </div>
  <div class="__aqua ">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try but it seems like it works but when I use scaling, it is not increasing in one set position. It is moving down in a diagonal.

Comment: you can try background-position: 50% 50%

Comment: Well I added "transform: translate" instead and it worked. Thanks for the help :D Really looks nice on Safari.

Comment: Hello, can you please help me make the circle better because svg is getting annoying to use and I am looking at a website that looks very similar to mine and they achieved it but I don't know how. Can you look at their code and tell me how they achieved it. Website is https://indiez.io

Comment: Is there a way I can message you? And I mean reading that is hard but I kinda understand. But can you explain where they got the HD color online mine?

Comment: Their scaling is more conservative for one. scale(5) vs your scale(50). Your border radius in 100%. If you are looking for a circle, 50% will do it (like theirs as well). Could you create a working code snippet of your solution?

Comment: Here is my code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWpXQw for the new circle. See how I still have the bad borders.

Comment: That's because they are sizing their bubble element @ 800px x 800px and setting initial scale to 0. So they are scaling up to actual size from a zoomed out state. Yours is 100px x 100px and your are scaling up, which is blowing the pixels up and you are seeing dithering. If I remember correctly, Chrome will accommodate fractional pixels, but Safari and some others won't. Look at the second block of CSS, just within the 600px media query, in my answer above. That should get your solution on track. I tested your codepen in safari and it's fine now. Don't forget the will-change:transform property

Comment: Oh I see but do I need that "._touch" and ":not(,_touch) part? And I changed it to 800px x 800px and it looks a little better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141844/discussion-between-ryan-w-and-thatoneguy90).